# Requisição via GET

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, pdo

Estou tentando criar um sistema de busca usando uma Requisição para obter o resultado da pesquisa.

Não estou conseguindo trazer os dados do produto referente ao titulo pesquisado.

Qualquer que seja a palavra pesquisada, ele sempre me traz o ultimo item da tabela produto.

Código para pesquisa ou busca abaixo:

```
<form action="prod_index_consulta.php" method="get">
    <span>Busca Avançada</span>
    <input type="image" name="busca" img src="img/search.gif" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="buscar"/>
</form>


<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.search').click(function(){
            var cod = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({url:"prod_index_consulta.php?buscar="+cod,success:function(data){
                $('#visual').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Abaixo código para receber os dados do produto, pesquisado pelo titulo:

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";
$buscar = $_GET['buscar']; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pagcabecalho, menu, produto WHERE titulo LIKE :pesquisa";
$resultados = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$resultados->bindParam(':pesquisa', $buscar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$resultados->execute();
foreach($resultados as $res){

echo'
<div id="prod" style="background-color:'.$res["fundosite_cor"].';width:33%; float:left; padding:10px 0;" class="center_prod_box">
    <div align="center" id="titulo" style="width:100%;">
        '.$res["titulo"].'
    </div>
    <div align="center" style="width:100%; height:130px; background-color:'.$res["fundosite_cor"].';">
        <div align="center">
            <a href="prod_detalhe_5.php?codigo='.$res["codigo"].'">
                <img style="width:100%; max-width:100px;" src="img_produtos/'.$res["img01"].'" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div align="center" id="preco" style="width:100%;">
        <span style="">R$ '.$res["preco"].'</span>
    </div>                        
    <div align="center" id="carrinho" style="width:100%;">
        <a href="prod_carrinho.php?acao=add&codigo='.$res["codigo"].'">
            <img style="width:100%; max-width:20px;" src="img/carrinho.png" title="Por no Carrinho" />
        </a>
    </div>                        
 </div>
';
}?>
```

Sou leigo no assunto e estou tentando aprender meio na marra, mas acho que o problema esteja nessa linha abaixo do script:

```
$.ajax({url:"prod_index_consulta.php?buscar="+cod,success:function(data){
```

Porque me da a impressão de que falta alguma coisa para ele buscar o produto de acordo com a pesquisa.

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma ajuda nessa questão, ficarei agradecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estou postando a solução que encontrei para trazer somente os dados referente a consulta realizada pelo titulo dos produtos.

O Código para pesquisa ou busca ficou assim:

```
<div>
   <span>Busca Avançada</span>    
   <input type="image" id="buscar" img src="img/search.gif" />    
   <input type="text" id="palavra" placeholder="Buscar por..."/>
</div>

<script>
function buscar(palavra){
    var page = "prod_index_consulta_5_img.php";
    $.ajax
            ({
                type:'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                url: page,
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $("#visual").html("Carregando...");
                },
                data: {palavra: palavra},
                success: function (msg)
                {
                    $("#visual").html(msg);
                }
            });
    }
    $('#buscar').click(function (){
        buscar($("#palavra").val())
});
</script>
```

O código para receber os dados do produto, pesquisado pelo titulo ficou assim:

```
<?php
    include "conexao.php";
    $palavra = $_GET['palavra']; 
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM produto WHERE titulo LIKE '%".$palavra."%'");
    $sql->execute();
    foreach($sql->fetchAll() as $res){

    echo'
    <div id="prod">
        <div align="center" id="titulo">
            '.$res["titulo"].'
        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <div align="center">
                <a href="prod_detalhe_5.php?codigo='.$res["codigo"].'">
                    <img src="img_produtos/'.$res["img01"].'" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div align="center" id="preco">
            <span>R$ '.$res["preco"].'</span>
        </div>                        
        <div align="center" id="carrinho">
            <a href="prod_carrinho.php?acao=add&codigo='.$res["codigo"].'">
                <img src="img/carrinho.png" title="Por no Carrinho" />
            </a>
        </div>                        
     </div>
    ';
    }
?>
```

Espero que seja útil à quem venha precisar.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pagcabecalho, menu, produto WHERE titulo LIKE :pesquisa";
$resultados = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$resultados->bindParam(':pesquisa', $buscar, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$resultados->execute();
while($res=$resultados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo'
    <div id="prod" style="background-color:'.$res["fundosite_cor"].';width:33%; float:left; padding:10px 0;" class="center_prod_box">
        <div align="center" id="titulo" style="width:100%;">
            '.$res["titulo"].'
        </div>
        <div align="center" style="width:100%; height:130px; background-color:'.$res["fundosite_cor"].';">
            <div align="center">
                <a href="prod_detalhe_5.php?codigo='.$res["codigo"].'">
                    <img style="width:100%; max-width:100px;" src="img_produtos/'.$res["img01"].'" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div align="center" id="preco" style="width:100%;">
            <span style="">R$ '.$res["preco"].'</span>
        </div>                        
        <div align="center" id="carrinho" style="width:100%;">
            <a href="prod_carrinho.php?acao=add&codigo='.$res["codigo"].'">
                <img style="width:100%; max-width:20px;" src="img/carrinho.png" title="Por no Carrinho" />
            </a>
        </div>
     </div>
    ';
}
```

Da forma que vc estava fazendo, o array `$resultados` iria mostrar apenas o ultimo mesmo, mas agora, vc separa o array dentro de um loop `while()` separando os resuldados de forma associativa com a função `fetch()` e o parâmetro `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`.

Comment: Olá Wees Smith, fiz a alteração que você recomendou, porém sem sucesso. Resolvi fazer com FORM e funcionou em parte. Ele me traz os dados pesquisados corretamente, mas não usando o SCRIPT,e sim a pagina que está no ACTION do FORM `<form action="prod_index_consulta.php" method="get">`. Editei o Código para pesquisa, com isso tem como você me mostrar como incremento ou faço para ele abrir na DIV #visual usando o SCRIPT?